# Select userid and sum of total amount of books a user has made on all loans

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get an output which displays the personID and the total sum of books the user has made throughout every loan.

Member:

| PersonID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Loan:

| PersonID | LoanID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

OrderLine:

| LoanID | BookID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |

Expected output:

| PersonID | Total sum of books |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |

Edit:
I have tried a couple of things, as I've been at this for about three hours now. Most of my attempts have been scrapped but this is one attempt I came up with which wasn't able to do my problem.

```sql
SELECT SUM(TOTAL) AS Test FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM Person AS P
    WHERE P.PersonID IN (
        SELECT PersonID FROM Loan AS L
        WHERE L.LoanID IN (
            SELECT LoanID FROM Orderline AS OL
            WHERE L.LoanID = OL.LoanID
            )
        )
    GROUP BY P.PersonID
) AS TOTAL;
```

Comment: As a hint, I suggest looking at `JOIN` syntax and aggregate functions. Both are fundamental parts of any SQL dialect, so if you aren't familiar with these you need to take the time to learn them.

Comment: Another hint, you're going to want a `COUNT` function, as opposed to a `SUM`, as implied by the column of your output. As Larnu stated, people want to see that you at least made an effort and didn't just post up your work for others to take care of for you. People here can be extremely helpful, but no one wants to be taken advantage of.

Comment: @Larnu I've tried using both but I'm still unsure how to do this exact SQL therefor I didn't post anything I've tried because it wasn't even close to solving my problem.

Comment: *"I've tried using both"* then [edit] your question with those attempts, @Andreasx23 Just dumping some data and expecting *us* to write your code for you is never going to go down well. Show the efforts and/or research you've done to answer your own question first.

Comment: @Larnu I've been at this for about three hours now so I no longer have past attempts, sorry :/. Thank you for giving me some tips for future posts. #Edit: I found one past attempt, will add it here.
SELECT SUM(TOTAL) AS Test FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM Person AS P
 WHERE P.PersonID IN (
  SELECT PersonID FROM Loan AS L
  WHERE L.LoanID IN (
   SELECT LoanID FROM Orderline AS OL
   WHERE L.LoanID = OL.LoanID
   )
  )
 GROUP BY P.PersonID
) AS TOTAL;

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put it in the comments.

Comment: @Larnu Oh. I have now edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count duplicated books :

```
SELECT 
        PersonID,
        count(*) as 'Total sum of books'
FROM
        Loan l
INNER JOIN
        OrderLine o on l.LoanID = o.LoanID
GROUP BY PersonID
```

For including users with 0 loan:

```
SELECT
        m.PersonID,
        CASE
             WHEN c.PersonID is not NULL THEN c.cpt
             ELSE 0
        END as 'Total sum of books'
FROM
        Member m
FULL JOIN
    (
         SELECT 
                PersonID,
                count(*) as cpt
         FROM
                Loan l
         INNER JOIN
                OrderLine o on l.LoanID = o.LoanID
         GROUP BY PersonID
    ) as c ON m.PersonId = c.PersonId
```

It's not the most elegant way to do it, but I think it's one of the easiest to understand.

With the full join will give you one counter (cpt) per user. If there is no match then cpt will be NULL.

Comment: It's for a school project so there is no member with 0 loans, but it would be nice if it was possible to do so :) - Thank you!

Comment: I'll not do your homework.

Be advised that professor can easily spot you on Stackoverflow (they are users themselves).

Comment: It's not homework it's for a project, but thank you nonetheless. Just as a side node teachers even encourge us to ask for help from stackoverflow if we're in doubt.

Comment: I edited the query to be more clear. Ask if you do not understand something.